# PCIe bus error, screen blacks out, restart required. Errors in syslog

Tags: laptop, hp, hardware

I am using HP pavilion au003tx notebook  with Ubuntu 19.04. Some times display goes just black and after restarting I can see hardware error in system logs. I have attached screenshot.

[image: screenshot of error]

Please help me because last time this happened I needed to replace mt battery.

Comment: The problem may be with your wireless adapter. See https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=221537 for a possible fix.

Comment: well I wireless works fine but after disabling bluetooth by editing kernel I have not noticed any display blanking. It has be just one day since I did that.

Comment: Bluetooth and wireless are usually on the same adapter/card. I'd check the web site for BIOS updates, firmware updates, or bluetooth/wireless card updates. To check the BIOS, use `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, then go to the manufacturer's web site to find if there's something newer.

Comment: I have latest BIOS for my system.

Comment: Lets check for bluetooth co-existence. `sudo lshw -C network`, note the driver for your wireless card, maybe something like rtxxxx, then `modinfo rtxxxx | grep -i btc`, look for `parm btcoexist=true`... or `modinfo rtxxxx | grep -i blue`.

Comment: This is output for sudo lshw -C network command for wireless: *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
logical name: wlo1
version: 81
serial: xx:xx:xx:xx
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-20-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=192.168.43.23 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
resources: irq:131 memory:94000000-94001fff

Comment: I cannot find drivers as rtxxxx, and in settings for Bluetooth, it says that Bluetooth is turned off and i did not see any option to turn it on after I edited  kernel.

Comment: In kernel i added "pci=noaer" in grub file loketed in etc/default in line "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT".

Comment: The correct command would have been `modinfo iwlwifi | grep bt` and it shows as enabled on my computer. When you say "edited kernel" do you mean changing kernel params in /etc/default/grub? Why did you add pci=noaer, and did it help fix the problem?

Comment: Before I edited kernel perams I was getting RxErr, so I searched on askubuntu and editing perams was given as solution. And I think it worked because after that I never got any problem regarding display blinking in Ubuntu. I still get that problem in Windows 10 and I have to restart system and work from zero, and after executing command in comment above I got following result: "parm:               bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)"                                                                                  And thank you.

Comment: The `pci=noaer` disables "advanced error reporting". The errors still occur. You just don't see them. And you can't turn on your bluetooth card? As I said in my very first comment, you may have a problem with your wireless/bluetooth card. I'd physically remove the wireless/bluetooth card, remove pci=noear, and see if the problem shows up again. Also on Windows... see if the problem is gone.

Comment: Well I did as been asked and I am not getting error as I was getting previously. But this is what I see in logs :"Failed to set mode: Blocked through frkill(0x12)" from bluetoothhd.

Comment: Use the `rfkill list all` and check for any "yes" lines. If bluetooth is blocked, use the `rfkill unblock` command. See `man rfkill` for details.

Comment: Done and having RxErr. In logs it is Hardware error. Message: pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:   device [8086:9d1b] error status/mask=00000001/00002000, Kernel Device: +pci:0000:00:1d.0. It says:  pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID). It is same RxErr I was getting previously in Fedora, Redhat and Debian. What this error indicates and how do I solve it?

Comment: Do `lspci -tv` and look for the line that contains `1d.0`. The rest of that same line will tell you what the device is. Question... when you did pci=noaer, did both the wireless and the bluetooth work properly? Does `rfkill list all` show any `yes` lines? Instead of pci=noaer, try `pcie_aspm=off` and see what happens.

Comment: Well, it looks like there is problem with my wifi card. My laptop has Intel AC-3165 wifi card. Answer would be Yes, even after I did pci=noaer my wfifi and Bluetooth were working properly, and no - no line shows 'yes' after running command rfkill show all. I have already tried pcei_aspm=off and there is same error in logs!

Comment: Did you try `pcie_aspm=off`?

Comment: yes, I have and i am having same error.

Comment: Well, then for now, stick with the pci=noaer. If you check the Internet, you'll find lots of reports similar to yours... but i don't see a definitive solution. As you also have Windows issues... know that there is some kind of problem there.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for everything.